# Safely drilling tile

Tags: plumbing, shower

During a remodel the contractor installed tile in a large shower.  Next was to install the sliding shower door.  The contractor tried drilling into some scrap tile and it broke/cracked the tile. So he refused to try to install the shower door. I think he didn't want to take on the liability of cracking the tile. So... now my questions are:

1. do I try to get another contractor with more expertise?
2. try to DIY?

   - If DIY what would be the best approach?
   - Maybe small drill followed by slightly larger and larger drills?
   - Or the third option I think would be to simply silicone it in place.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How big of a hole needs to be drilled?

Comment: What type of drill did the contractor fail with? There are options these days. The "classic tile drill bit" sucks majorly in my experience.

Comment: There are special drill bits for tile; several types in fact. People drill tile all the time and there should be no problem. What kind of tile is this--ordinary (softer) ceramic or (much harder) porcelain? Do you know where the studs are behind the tile?

Comment: We use plastic shower curtains in a tub-shower and in a walk in shower. It works fine. Do you already have the sliding door on the premises? On the tub-shower I installed an outward curving rod by drilling two or three holes in each end in the soft ordinary ceramic tile. Gives a lot more shoulder room and gets the curtain far enough away from the shower that the stream does not pull the curtain in. This gives plenty of access to wash the dog by me neelling beside the tub.  In the other bathroom we have a spring shower rod not in a socket. This is not ideal but is tolerable.

Comment: Your question is all over the place. We can't tell you how to deal with your contractor. That's a subjective thing and a matter of opinion. We also can't answer your implied question about mounting your shower with silicone because you haven't provided enough detail. Please revise to make your question more clear and only about home improvement.

Comment: The chances are the test tile was not supported well, unlike (hopefully) the tiles on the wall, with their adhesive backing. Some tiles are *extremely* hard, so go with answers below. Otherwise, drill through the gaps between if at all possible.

Comment: Find  a competent contractor. he will have the equipment and knowledge.

Comment: Is it Porcelain tile or Ceramic tile?

Answer (score 5):

Simple rule: The harder the material is the more teeth is needed to prevent cracking.

Any drill with two cutting surfaces is not good for tiles. Use a diamond drill. Don't apply pressure and use plenty of water as coolant and lubricant.